# when searching for text, get paths in dotted notation

Tags: jq

I'm pretty new to jq.

For the JSON at the bottom of this post, I can do

```sh
jq '[paths as $path | select(getpath($path) == "Standard Generalized Markup Language") | $path ]' json.json
```

and get

```
[
  [
    "glossary",
    "GlossDiv",
    "GlossList",
    "GlossEntry",
    "GlossTerm"
  ]
]
```

How can I modify that query so that I get the paths like this?

`glossary.GlossDiv.GlossList.GlossEntry.GlossTerm`

### `json.json`

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`join` the path array items using the dot as delimiter.

Following your approach using `paths` and `getpath`:

```
[
  paths as $path
  | select(getpath($path) == "Standard Generalized Markup Language")
  | $path | join(".")
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/pGy-GMI_K-)

Using `..`, `strings` and `path`:

```
[
  path(.. | select(strings == "Standard Generalized Markup Language")) 
  | join(".")
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ySH4-E0TzV)

Using `tostream`:

```
[
  tostream | select(.[1] == "Standard Generalized Markup Language")[0]
  | join(".")
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/wY8bTDbMJh)

```json
[
  "glossary.GlossDiv.GlossList.GlossEntry.GlossTerm"
]
```

If you want a stream (instead of an array) of strings, omit the top-level brackets altogether.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a Bash script call [`jqg`](https://github.com/NorthboundTrain/jqg/) that will flatten JSON files and filter the results producing valid JSON output; it does pretty much what you want in a generic fashion.

Running the script with your JSON and with "Standard Generalized Markup Language" as the search string yields the following:

```
$ jqg "Standard Generalized Markup Language" /tmp/json.json
{
  "glossary.GlossDiv.GlossList.GlossEntry.GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language"
}
```

You can opt to only give the path elements and not the value:

```
$ jqg -K "Standard Generalized Markup Language" /tmp/json.json
[
  "glossary.GlossDiv.GlossList.GlossEntry.GlossTerm"
]
```

and if you want the path as a string and not as full JSON, you can do that, too:

```
$ jqg -r -K "Standard Generalized Markup Language" /tmp/json.json
glossary.GlossDiv.GlossList.GlossEntry.GlossTerm
```

Note: I am the author of `jqg`.